# How to get data from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

How to correctly transfer data from a fragment to an activity? I do as follows:
1- Create an interface

```
interface IProfileToActivity {
    fun profileInfo(data: AllHeroes.Global)
}
```

2- Then I inheritance in the activity

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IProfileToActivity {
private lateinit var myBinding: ActivityProfileBinding
    override fun profileInfo(data: AllHeroes.Global) {
        myBinding.tvUsername.text = data.name
        myBinding.tvDivision.text = data.rank.rankName
        Log.i("Apex Info 3", data.toString())
    }
}
```

3- sending from a fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  (activity as? IProfileToActivity)?.profileInfo(allInfoApexResponse.global)
                mHeroesAdapter.heroesList(allAdapterListHero)
}
```

but nothing happens, why?  what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can use a Shared `ViewModel`. Store and update the mutable live data inside it and scope it to the MainAcitivity.
You can also make use of `Communicator`

Comment: @AbhishekDutt can you show this with an example? Please

Comment: Why has this question been closed? It's not about passing data to container activity.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I don't know why ((In fact, I did the same as in that example

Comment: @Ethernets I suggest you should post another question with more details explaining where you want to send the data.

Comment: @ArpitShukla ok, don't go far, I'll create a new topic now. thanks

Comment: @ArpitShukla https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837001/how-to-get-data-from-fragment-to-activity-not-container-activity new post

Answer (score 4):

You need not create an interface here. You can use `requireActivity()` to get a reference to the parent activity. Using it you can access public fields and functions of you activity.

```kotlin
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var myBinding: ActivityProfileBinding

    fun profileInfo(data: AllHeroes.Global) {
        myBinding.tvUsername.text = data.name
        myBinding.tvDivision.text = data.rank.rankName
        Log.i("Apex Info 3", data.toString())
    }
}
```

And in your fragment:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (requireActivity as ProfileToActivity).profileInfo(allInfoApexResponse.global)
    mHeroesAdapter.heroesList(allAdapterListHero)
}
```

Comment: i got error ```java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.apextracker.view.activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.apextracker.view.activities.ProfileActivity``` i think this is due to the fact that ProfileActivity is not a parent of the fragment

Comment: So, the parent of your fragment is MainActivity but you want to send data to ProfileActivity. Is it so?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Where is Profile Activity? Is it in the back stack?

Comment: ProfileActivity is a separate activity from a fragment, which is launched when the menu is called ```override fun onOptionsItemSelected (item: MenuItem): Boolean {
         when (item.itemId) {
             R.id.action_profile -> {
                 (requireActivity () as ProfileActivity) .profileInfo (testApex)
                 startActivity (Intent (requireActivity (), ProfileActivity :: class.java))
                 return true
             }
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected (item)
     }```

Comment: and in this separate activity me need to transfer the data pool

Comment: So what you want is to launch a new activity (ProfileActivity) when user selects "Profile" from overflow menu, and you want to pass some data to that ProfileActivity at the same time. RIght?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to pass data from fragment to activity:

Using shared `ViewModel`.

> A `ViewModel` is used to manage and store UI related data in a
> lifecycle conscious way.
> ~Read more

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val currItems: MutableLiveData<List<Item>> =
        MutableLiveData<List<Item>>(listOf())

    fun getCurrItem(): LiveData<List<Item>> {
        return currItems
    }

    fun sendCurrItems(items: MutableList<Item>) {
        currItems.postValue(items)
    }
}
class ItemFragment: Fragment() {
    private val sharedModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
}

MainActivity: AppCompactActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

In the above class, data is being stored and updated using an `MutableList`. Thing to be noted here is, the above class is a `singleton` class, i.e. once it is created, it gets destroyed only when the activity is ended.

Let us assume that an `item` has to be shared from a `ItemFragment` to the `MainActivity`

One callback has to be implemented the `MainActivity`. For that, one can use an `Interface`

```
interface ItemListener{
    fun sendItem(item : MutableList<Item>)
}
```

`ItemFragment`:

```
class ItemFragment: Fragment() {
   
   override fun sendItems(items: MutableList<Item>?) {
        // Send an Item from here as well as update it
    }
    // Or just simply call sendItem method.
}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompactActivity(){
    
    fun receiveItem(context : Context){
       
      private var mCallback: ItemListener? = null
      mCallback = context
     }

}
```